# Create dynamic Two.js variables to involve individual click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, two.js

In creating a [two.js](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/#documentation) object, here are the parts:

```
var circle1 = two.makeCircle(676,326,25);
circle1.noStroke().fill = getRandomColor();
circle1.domElement = document.querySelector('#two-' + circle1.id);
$(circle1.domElement)
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(function(e) {
        circle1.fill = getNonMainRandomColor(getRandomColor());
    });
```

I tried to save all the necessary parameters in an array as such:

`[x position, y position, radius, color]`

So I have the function

```
function showCircles(array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var rotato = two.makeCircle(array[i][0],array[i][1],array[i][2]);
    rotato.noStroke().fill = array[i][3];
    rotato.domElement = document.querySelector('#two-' + rotato.id);
    $(rotato.domElement).css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(e) {rotato.fill = getNonMainRandomColor(getRandomColor());});
  } 
}
```

The problem with the latter is that the lines

```
    rotato.domElement = document.querySelector('#two-' + rotato.id);
    $(rotato.domElement).css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(e) {rotato.fill = getNonMainRandomColor(getRandomColor());});
```

require a fresh variable every time it is fired thus the output is a group of circles that when clicked individually, only the last one changes color because of the setting that I have which is caused by `var rotato` that should be new every circle and iteration.

How do I make the variable dynamic or is there a better solution to this mess?

[Here is a codepen fork](http://cdpn.io/qDvxA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that JavaScript's `for` statement doesn't create closures for each iteration. As a result when any of the circles is clicked it looks for what the reference to `rotato`. This variable is reused for each iteration and the result is what you're referring to as the *last* item in the array.

I've forked and made a new codepen that uses [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'s `map` method which is bundled in two.js. This is similar to a `for` statement except that for each iteration it creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) making independent references to each of the `rotato` variables you're constructing.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ylzvx

Comment: As of this moment the API has changed so the click events do not work. See this example for how click events work now with two.js: http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/examples/svg-events.html