# How to capture a click event on a shape or group in two.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, two.js

I have drawn a shape using two.js and I want to write code to handle click events on that shape. Not the canvas, but on the shape itself.

```
front_left.domElement = $('#two-' + front_left.id)
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(function(e){
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
```

This code [taken from an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457600/254477) that seems like it should work:

```
circle.domElement = $('#two-' + circle.id)
  .css('cursor', 'pointer')
  .click(function(e) {
    circle.fill = getNonMainRandomColor(getRandomColor());
  });
```

but it doesn't work for me using the latest JQuery and the latest two.js, and it also doesn't seem to work in [the example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ylzvx), since the code reads as if clicking on the circles was supposed to make the colour changes but nothing happens on any browser or computer I've tried.

So, how can I capture and respond to click events of shapes/groups drawn with two.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the message. The reason this answer doesn't work anymore is because two.js has changed since then. I've added an [example here](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/examples/svg-events.html). The gist of it is that:

1. Use the `svg` renderer
2. Whenever you create a shape it will have a private property `_renderer`
3. You can access the `elem` which is its corresponding dom element
4. *But!* make sure that the renderer has updated before you access it

e.g:

```
var shape = two.makeCircle(two.width / 2, two.height / 2, 50);
two.update();
shape._renderer.elem.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
```

And, if you're feeling adventurous you can mix renderers like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jonobr1/6cw5nz5p/).

Comment: Is this answer still relevant? Seems to work fine, I was wondering whether there was an easier way added.